# rails api instagram jquery env in heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

How can I configure the heroku env in javascript in rails for an instagram api this is just my code

```
var token = <%= ENV['MY_API_TOKEN'] %>,
userid = <%= ENV['MY_API_USERID'] %>,
num_photos = 10;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + userid + '/media/recent/?access_token=' + token,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      for( x in data.data ){
        $("#container").append('<li><img src="'+data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url+'"></li>');
      }
    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

The only thing that echo is to change js by js.erb and already put the key in env of heroku

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

go to to your app page on heroku then

**Settings** -> in Config Variables section click on **Reveal Config Vars**
and then just insert your key